Badge doesn't show up at all on Android Views
I want to attach a Badge to different Views. But the Badge doesn't show up at all.
Here's my main_activity.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_delete"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:text="Test 1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/materialbutton"
        android:text="Test 1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>

Here's my corresponding Activity:
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import androidx.annotation.OptIn
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.google.android.material.badge.BadgeDrawable
import com.google.android.material.badge.BadgeUtils
import com.google.android.material.badge.ExperimentalBadgeUtils
import de.molkow.badgetest.databinding.ActivityMainBinding

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        setBadge(binding.imageview)
        setBadge(binding.button)
        setBadge(binding.materialbutton)
    }

    @OptIn(ExperimentalBadgeUtils::class)
    private fun setBadge(view: View) {
        val badge = BadgeDrawable.create(this)
        badge.number = 5
        badge.setVisible(true)
        BadgeUtils.attachBadgeDrawable(badge, view)
    }
}

Each of the 3 Views (ImageView, Button, MaterialButton) should show a Badge but doesn't. The Views themselves show, but not their Badges. What am I doing wrong?
This is what is shown:
No Badges shown
